# Store Variables/Arrays/Objects in C++ object for Python

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

Is it possible to store variables/arrays/objects in a C++ Object to store and modify such data through Python? For example, I want to store arrays/vectors of points/polygons/voxels/etc in a C++ Object in Python. And sometimes, I want to do something with them (change/add/remove).

Here is my simple code, but I've got an Exception:

C++:

```
class Foo{

    public:

    std::vector<openvdb::Vec3s> vertices_test;

    void generateArray(std::vector<openvdb::Vec3s> ar){

        // JUST DO SOMETHING GENERIC 
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                ar.push_back(openvdb::Vec3s(0.3, 0.1, 0.2));
            }
    }


};

extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) Foo* Foo_new(){ return new Foo(); }
    __declspec(dllexport) void Foo_generateArray(Foo* foo){ foo->generateArray(foo->vertices_test); }

}
```

Python part:

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.obj = lib.Foo_new()

    def generateArray(self):
        lib.Foo_generateArray(self.obj)


f = Foo()
f.generateArray()
```

But when I run Python I get an exception:

```
OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000058ED7D28
```

As you can see I tried to store **std::vectoropenvdb::Vec3s vertices_test** object as a local variable in the C++ Object. But it looks like something goes wrong.

Also, is it possible to return float/int in the generateArray() function instead of void?
Thanks you.

Comment: Please, do not describe C++ as "C/C++". That's a nonsensical term. C has "objects" but they are a completely different concept than C++ "object-oriented" objects. That this uses a C interface is just an artifact of how Python binds, it's totally normal and doesn't make this C/C++ code.

Comment: "Access violation" usually means "accessed an invalid pointer".

Comment: Note that your `generateArray()` function takes in a copy of the argument, modifies it, then throws that away.

Answer (score 0):

From [the `ctypes` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#return-types):

> By default functions are assumed to return the C `int` type. Other return types can be specified by setting the `restype` attribute of the function object.

Your question implies that you're on 64-bit Windows, and on 64-bit Windows, pointers are 8 bytes and `int`s are only 4 bytes, so the upper 4 bytes of your pointer are being lost.

Comment: Thank you a lot but the main question is about storing a local variable in a C++ class.